# Outlook 2007 client-side rules on a shared mailbox - not automatic

Tags: microsoft-outlook, exchange, mailbox

Anyone seen this issue before - a user has to manually select and run his Outlook rules for a shared Mailbox. For some reason the do not run automatically. Known issue perhaps? Runs fine for his Inbox.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to be logged into an Outlook profile that has the shared mailbox as it's primary account to be able to set automatic/server-side rules for it.

You can (should) only set server-side rules for that mailbox (via that profile) so that it will fire off even with no one logged into that profile (or Outlook).

Found a decent set of (example) instructions for you [here](https://kis.kellogg.northwestern.edu/Pages/ExchangeAutoResponseShared.aspx) that outlines setting up an auto-responder for a shared mailbox. Here is is in a slightly edited form:

> You can create automatic
>   email responses in Microsoft Outlook
>   2007 that originate from a
>   non-personal email account. To automatically
>   respond to messages, set up a shared
>   mailbox; and use rules in Outlook 2007
>   to have the mail server automatically
>   reply to messages.
>
> Setting up a second Outlook profile
>
> To set up an Outlook AutoResponse from
>   a shared mailbox, you need to create a
>   second Outlook profile that connects
>   only to the shared mailbox:
>
> 1. Click the Start menu, select Control
>      Panel, and double-click Mail. The
>      "Mail Setup" box appears.
> 2. Click Show
>      Profiles, choose Prompt for a profile
>      to be used, and click Add, and type
>      in the name of your new profile. Click
>      OK.
> 3. Check Manually configure server
>      settings… and click Next.
> 4. Select
>      Microsoft Exchange, click Next, and
>      enter the Microsoft Exchange server
>      name.
> 5. In the
>      User Name field, enter the shared
>      mailbox name.
> 6. Click
>      Next to finish the wizard.
>
> To send a response with a customized
>   subject and message to every message:
>
> 1. Launch Outlook and select the profile
>      you created above.
> 2. Select the Inbox,
>      and click Tools > Rules and Alerts.
> 3. Click New Rule and click Check
>      messages when they arrive.
> 4. Click Next
>      twice (don’t do anything in the "What
>      condition(s) do you want to check?"
>      box.)
> 5. Select have server reply using
>      a specific message, and click …a
>      specific message. A blank email
>      appears.
> 6. In the Subject and Message
>      fields, type the message you want to
>      send. Leave the To, CC, and BCC (if
>      showing) fields blank
> 7. Click Save and
>      Close to close the message window and
>      click Next.
> 8. Select the appropriate
>      exclusion option (if any) and click
>      Next.
> 9. Name the rule (do not check the
>      Run this rule… checkbox.) and check
>      Turn on this rule.
> 10. Click Finish.
> 11. You can now close Outlook and
>       re-launch it using your profile.
>
> For
>   any message that you receive in the
>   shared mailbox, the server will send
>   an automatic reply to sender whether
>   or not Outlook is running on your
>   computer.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Finally, an answer that works! Thank you very much!